# Disable UIView rendering while scaling

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I have a `UIView` that is built with several `CALayers` to display the contents.

This view then has a set of gesture recognizers to move it around and change its transform and size.

They all work fine except that when the scale is applied there seems to be a delay in updating the `CALayers` to be the correct size. This gives it a really glitchy animation and looks really bad.

I can stop the `CALayers` from resizing by setting a boolean on the `.Began` and `.Ended` for the `recognizer.state` but that just makes it keep the same size until you let go and it pops to the new size.

What I'd like to do is to somehow turn the view into a flat view (like an image) that scales when I pinch just by upscaling the contents. And then when I let go it renders the `CALayers` properly again.

Is there a sensible way to do this?